# How can I add extra commands/arguments when opening Command Prompt with PsExec?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, shortcuts, psexec

I'm creating a shortcut to open Command Prompt with SYSTEM privileges, it works fine, but I want the title of the resulting cmd window to be clearly labeled with something like "SYSTEM".

So I want to do something *like* this:

```
PsExec -d -i -s cmd "title SYSTEM"
```

But obviously that last bit in quotes isn't the correct syntax because it doesn't work.

Comment: It works, but gets overwritten by the remote that likes to print the path. If you instead run batch remotely you can change the title from there.

Comment: @FrankSixteen What do you mean by running a batch remotely? How do I do that?